# passing StackFrame Stack trace from derived class

Tags: c#, debugging, design-patterns, stack-frame

i have a base class that accepts a `StackFrame` parameter.

```
public ExcpM(string Msg, StackFrame parCallStack = null, bool show = true)
{
    StackFrame LcallStack;
    if (parCallStack == null)
       LcallStack= new StackFrame(1, true);
    else LcallStack= parCallStack;

        //do stuff with info in LcallStack ..
}
```

originally i have started without the said parameter, i have added it because
when using a common Extension method or any method that calls the above constructor,
without the added parameter `callStack.GetMethod()` will then give the extension method data rather the intended caller which is the one i was after.

now that i called it as a solution, there comes a new problem that i am stuck without a proper solution for, which starts me thinking i am using it incorrectly.

the problem is when i created a derived class from the above `ExcpM` main class
which also gives the wrong guy data (the derived own ctor..)

derived (added a false return value for Boolean methods usage)

```
public class ExcpFlsV:ExcpM
{
    bool Rtrn { get { return false; } }
    public ExcpFlsV(string bsMsg, StackFrame bsCallStack = null)
      : base(bsMsg, bsCallStack)
    {

    }
}
```

usage

```
public bool someMethodReturnsBool()
{
    //unless adding Local callStack field to every method passes ctor of ExcpFlsV as calling method
    StackFrame LcallStack = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1, true);
    if(some condition no met) 
      return new ExcpFlsV("some error message...", LcallStack).Rtrn;
}
```

**what is the proper way to pass the caller method as the data ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool SecondLevel(string caller, int callerLvl = 2)
{
    return testStacktrace(" called by SecondLevel " + caller, callerLvl);
}
public bool testStacktraceFirstLvl(string caller, int callerLvl = 1)
{

    new ExcpM("testStacktrace " + caller, callerLvl); return false;

}

public ExcpM(string Msg,int CallerLevel=1, bool show = true)
{
    StackFrame callStack = new StackFrame(CallerLevel, true);
    this.lnNum = callStack.GetFileLineNumber();
    this.fl = callStack.GetFileName();
    this.mthod = callStack.GetMethod().Name;
    this.lMsg = Msg;
}
```

or with derived (False version) , skipping an extra Stack Frame

```
public class ExcpFlsV:ExcpM
{
    bool Rtrn { get { return false; } }
    public ExcpFlsV(string bsMsg, int CallerLevel=2)
        : base(bsMsg, CallerLevel)
    {

    }
}

public bool SecondLevel(string caller, int callerLvl = 3)
{
    return testStacktrace(" called by SecondLevel " + caller, callerLvl);
}
public bool testStacktraceFirstLvl(string caller, int callerLvl = 2)
{
  return new ExcFlsBlV("testStacktrace " + caller, calLvl).Rtrn;
}
```